# Is this continuous right?

Tags: present-participles, present-continuous

> a low-hung, two-wheeled, covered vehicle drawn by one horse, for two passengers, with the driver **being** mounted on an elevated seat behind and the reins **running** over the roof.

The first one should be "with the driver mounted..." no? Because it is not continuous.

The second one is reins that run over the roof right?

Comment: The first one is fine as-is, and the second one means what you think it means. I can't wait for someone to explain _why_ the first is okay. Good question, though.

Comment: I'm going to go with this: the phrase is a transformation of "The driver is mounted on an elevated seat behind and the reins run over the roof" into a gerund phrase functioning as the object of the preposition *with*.

Comment: It's all ok, but archaic.  In modern times we would express it more the way you suggested.  What is the date of the passage you quoted?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think those are example of use of *Continuous Tense*.  They are *Present Participles*, yes, and to form *Continuous Tense* one uses the Present Participle of the verb, but that's the only connection.

I believe those are what's known as adjectival phrases.  A couple of examples:

> The animal **cowering in the corner** was rescued.
>   The horse **trotting up to the fence** snorted.
>   Mariah risked petting the pit bull **wagging its stub tail**.

(in the latter sentence the *pit bull* is defined by the phrase, not *Mariah*, by the way)